# Share video from android phone to facebook

Tags: android, facebook, youtube, youtube-api

I am developing a video recorder in android. It is a requirement that a user should be able to share/upload this video to his/her facebook account or Youtube account.
Do i need to use facebook and youtube APIs for this purpose or is there any easier way to share it from android phone to Internet.
It maybe a silly question but take me as a immature and new to programming world.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

There are two different approaches:

1) Upload to YouTube via [Data API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/) then get the video id and send the link to Facebook using Facebook API.
(If you want your video available outside FB and reach to larger audience)

2) Upload to Facebook directly with Facebook API. (If you want to have your video straight to FB and share it only in FB.)

Answer (score 0):

Yeah its possible talhamalik

You have use the Intent.ACTION_SEND, and the system will display a list of applications (on the device) where you can share. This website explains how:

http://sudarmuthu.com/blog/sharing-content-in-android-using-action_send-intent